# Allow element to overflow in table with table-layout:fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

A few threads exist on this topic but none of them have worked for me.

I have a HTML table element containing standard rows and columns, and I am trying to introduce subheaders to break up the data. The subheader needs to overlap (overflow into) a few columns to the right of it as it will often be wider than the first data column

Here's the table

```css
.REMOVETHISANDITWILLWORK {
  /*display:none;*/
}


.datatable {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 8pt;
  /* stop chrome highlighting table which is focussed to allow key scrolling */
}

.datatable>.scrollingdiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* record selectors in first td */

.datatable>.scrollingdiv>table>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.datatable table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv tr {
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv td {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 13px;
}


.datatable .scrollingdiv tr.trh {
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv .trh td {
  border-right: none;
  background-color: #f4f7fd;
  cursor: default;
}

td.th>div {}

td.th1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.th2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatable" tabindex="0">
  <div class="scrollingdiv" style="height: 797px;">
    <table style="width: 1429px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="trh trh1 REMOVETHISANDITWILLWORK">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th1" colspan="14">Contracts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2 REMOVETHISANDITWILLWORK">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Hardware Maintenance Contract</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1622" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1622</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">IBM Hardware Maintenance Contract 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534211</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Hardware Maintenance Contract</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Lease</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1621" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1621</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Server Lease 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534210</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Lease</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Software License Agreement</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1307" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1307</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Corporate SPLA Standard Enrollment 938746</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533896</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">938746</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1308" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1308</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Standard OPEN License Confirmation Number 127543</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533897</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">127543</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above the headers display, but its ignored column width and every column has the same width.

When the subheader td's exist the columns in the data lose their width even though its stamped on each TD with a style.

When the subheader td's do not exist or are hidden with display:none (uncomment that bit of css to try it), the columns in the table now size correctly respecting the width specified in style

Its all to do with the formatting of the first row - if we hide the first row, even if subsequent subheaders exist, it works ok. But of course the whole point of headers is you need them at the top.

I've tried giving subheader rows the same number of TD's as the data rows, and the same "width styling", but I then can't get the text to flow out of its TD so it gets chopped. It nearly works with display:inline; on that TD - but that makes the first column in the data rows disappear.

Here's the snippet with the columns how they should be, but the first subheaderrows had to be removed:

```css
.datatable {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 8pt;
  /* stop chrome highlighting table which is focussed to allow key scrolling */
}

.datatable>.scrollingdiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* record selectors in first td */

.datatable>.scrollingdiv>table>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.datatable table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv tr {
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv td {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 13px;
}


.datatable .scrollingdiv tr.trh {
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv .trh td {
  border-right: none;
  background-color: #f4f7fd;
  cursor: default;
}

td.th>div {}

td.th1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.th2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatable" tabindex="0">
  <div class="scrollingdiv" style="height: 797px;">
    <table style="width: 1429px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr data-k0="1622" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1622</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">IBM Hardware Maintenance Contract 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534211</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Hardware Maintenance Contract</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Lease</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1621" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1621</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Server Lease 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534210</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Lease</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Software License Agreement</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1307" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1307</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Corporate SPLA Standard Enrollment 938746</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533896</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">938746</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1308" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1308</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Standard OPEN License Confirmation Number 127543</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533897</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">127543</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above, the columns have the correct width, but we had to remove the first headers to achieve this.

And finally I hope, here's the fiddle with the first subheader row mimicing the data rows - if we can get the text in "This is a long header chopped" to flow out of its TD without messing up the rest of the table, that will do the job.

```css
.datatable {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 8pt;
  /* stop chrome highlighting table which is focussed to allow key scrolling */
}

.datatable>.scrollingdiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* record selectors in first td */

.datatable>.scrollingdiv>table>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.datatable table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv tr {
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv td {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 13px;
}


.datatable .scrollingdiv tr.trh {
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv .trh td {
  border-right: none;
  background-color: #f4f7fd;
  cursor: default;
}

td.th>div {}

td.th1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.th2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatable" tabindex="0">
  <div class="scrollingdiv" style="height: 797px;">
    <table style="width: 1429px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="trh trh1 REMOVETHISANDITWILLWORK">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th1" style="width: 30px;">This is a longer header chopped</td>
          <td style="width: 240px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 60px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 130px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;"></td>
          <td style="display: none;"></td>
          <td style="display: none;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1622" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1622</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">IBM Hardware Maintenance Contract 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534211</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Hardware Maintenance Contract</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Lease</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1621" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1621</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Server Lease 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534210</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Lease</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Software License Agreement</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1307" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1307</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Corporate SPLA Standard Enrollment 938746</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533896</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">938746</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1308" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1308</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Standard OPEN License Confirmation Number 127543</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533897</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">127543</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above, the columns have the correct width, and the headers are displaying, but the top header is getting chopped because it can only be as wide as the first TD.

Comment: I updated my answer. Commenting here in case you didn't get the @ tag notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `td` to a `th` will solve the issue.

Change:

```
<td class="th1" style="width: 30px;">This is a longer header chopped</td>
```

To:

```
<th class="th1" style="width: 30px;">This is a longer header chopped</th>
```

```css
.datatable {
  outline: none;
  font-size: 8pt;
  /* stop chrome highlighting table which is focussed to allow key scrolling */
}

.datatable>.scrollingdiv {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

/* record selectors in first td */

.datatable>.scrollingdiv>table>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  width: 16px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.datatable table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv tr {
  height: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv td {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px 0 1px 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 13px;
}


.datatable .scrollingdiv tr.trh {
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
}

.datatable .scrollingdiv .trh td {
  border-right: none;
  background-color: #f4f7fd;
  cursor: default;
}

td.th>div {}

td.th1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.th2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="datatable" tabindex="0">
  <div class="scrollingdiv" style="height: 797px;">
    <table style="width: 1429px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="trh trh1 REMOVETHISANDITWILLWORK">
          <td></td>
          <th class="th1" style="width: 30px;">This is header is NO longer chopped</th>
          <td style="width: 240px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 60px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 130px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;"></td>
          <td style="display: none;"></td>
          <td style="display: none;"></td>   
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1622" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1622</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">IBM Hardware Maintenance Contract 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534211</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Hardware Maintenance Contract</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Lease</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1621" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1621</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Server Lease 2018-2019</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00534210</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Lease</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="trh trh2">
          <td></td>
          <td class="th th2" colspan="14">Contracts - Software License Agreement</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1307" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1307</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Corporate SPLA Standard Enrollment 938746</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533896</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">938746</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-k0="1308" data-k1="1" class="">
          <td></td>
          <td style="width: 30px;">1308</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 240px;">Standard OPEN License Confirmation Number 127543</td>
          <td style="width: 60px;">00533897</td>
          <td class="editrecord ba" style="width: 130px;">Default Custodian</td>
          <td style="width: 120px;">Software License Agreement</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;">127543</td>
          <td class="assetlink ba" style="width: 120px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Department</td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Location</td>
          <td style="width: 150px;"></td>
          <td style="width: 100px;">Default Cost Centre</td>
          <td style="display: none;">Contracts</td>
          <td style="display: none;">1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now all the columns are the same width - we need them to respect the widths hard coded on each TD

Comment: @user2728841 Sorry about that, I missed the widths changing when I submitted initially. I have updated my answer, which is actually an even simpler solution.

Comment: Wow I started out with th's and then switched to td's long before starting this post - thanks I will get it in there now and see if it works in the product

Comment: @user2728841 Looks like you may have to update the CSS to include the `th` for the background color.